# tinymce 4.x - Change theme

Tags: tinymce-4

How do I change theme in tinyMCE 4.x?
I saw theme: Modern.
I googled and saw 'Simple', but that does not work for me.

What I want is the newest tiny with the 3.x look.

So, I want Theme: Classic.
Something like this: [tinymce](http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/tinymce31.jpg)

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried 'advanced'?